# How can I access User Info with AngularJS after NodeJS verification?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, passport.js

I've seen a few questions regarding this but being new to both Angular and Node I'm struggling to find a proper solution.

I had this code, which worked for the login and I could only access my pages after being authenticated:

```
router.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local',
            {
                successRedirect: '/',
                failureRedirect: '/login',
                failureFlash: false,
                successFlash: false
            }
    ));

router.all('*', ensureAuthenticated);

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    console.log("in ensureAuth", req.isAuthenticated());
    console.log("session data", req.session);
    console.log("user data", req.user);
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
    {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

The local passport authentication I have returns an object after verifying if the user exists and allows login, as such:

```
return passportDone(null, result.rows[0]);
```

with result.rows[0] being the user info I want.

What I had in the front end is a simple ng-submit in the form that calls the "login(credentials)" with credentials being set by ng-model in their respective fields (username and password).

My question is how can I return all the info I want, such as user_role, name and stuff, so I can present it in the front-end as {{user.name}} for example?

The info needs to stay after refreshes so $scope isn't an option from what I've read.

Comment: Create a service to manage login request and store response in that service so it is available across the whole angular app. There are lots of tutorials around for this

Comment: The problem I have is the authentication is already done with passport. I don't really understand how the request works. I found a really good example for the angular part but upon login it expected a req object with content that wasn't what the node app returned. The node app is returning in req.data the html code for the index page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do here, is create a custom route for fetching this information. for example: "/me".

In this route, you can serve the information you now probably store in your session variable.

Another solution, depending on how your application works with authentication, is to inject the userinfo (For example if you log in, and get redirected to a new page, you can inject the userinfo into the new page as a js variable) or to return the userinfo in the response if you send a ajax request to login and dont get redirected to a new page by the server.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using `passport.js` local authentication.I would recommend to store user infomation after authentication in cookies as a json webtoken or using some other encryption.And you should expose an api(/api/is-authenticated) which is used to check whether the user is authenticated, by sending the token stored in cookies.when ever you refresh or navigate to other routes make an api(/api/is-authenticated) call to check whether that particular user has already authenticated or not.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using passport. I believe I have that /api/is-authenticated as this:

router.all('*', ensureAuthenticated);


From what I understood, it redirects all to ensureAuthenticated which is on the post itself.

Comment: Ok, I experimented a bit and what's happening is, the response that the server gives is the index.html, due to having  '/' as the successRedirect. Instead of responding with something useful, it gives back the index page... Know how I can change that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.

I already had the service and all but the problem was with passport's successfulRedirect. It returns the html you want when it succeeds, which is fine. However, since I wanted the user info, it wasn't enough. What I did was create an /account route that returns the req.user info, which I then handle in the front end and form a cookie with it. What basically happens is:

post_login->verify_user->success->get_account->form_cookie->render_html